# Jquery Chrome changing image source makes image disappear until returned to original src

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

So I wrote some Jquery code to change the source attribute of an image on mouse hover. This code runs in other browsers I have tested in, expect for Chrome. The situation I run into with Chrome is the image will change in the HTML however, the image never appears.

UPDATE -- It has something to do with the hover image. I changed the hoverSrc to another images link and everything works fine. So either something is wrong with the link, or something is wrong with Chrome and loading a new .svg file.

Another UPDATE -- Something is wrong with the image. Displaying it using an img tag in Chrome displays nothing. However, viewing it directly with a link in chrome works fine.

Another UPDATE -- I am convinced that the issue is with Chrome and this specific svg file. I cannot simply display just the image I want using Chrome. So how would I detect that something is wrong with my SVG file that Chrome cannot load it.

Food for thought:

1. The src does change, however Chrome never goes out and loads the image, therefore never displays it.
2. I am using a relative url, potentially switching to a full url will force downloading the new image. -- Tested and didn't change anything.
3. Jquery does something different regarding Chrome and changing image sources, so I need to code a situational Chrome code to execute.
4. I placed an image besides the current image with display:none, so that the image will load into the cache. -- Tested and didn't change anything.

Code Block:

```
//StateWhite
    var originalSrc;
    var hoverSrc = "Content/Images/Maps/Complete Map With Color.svg";
    $('#StateWhite').hover(function () {
        //Hover is active. //Change img src
        originalSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        $('#StateWhite').attr("src", hoverSrc);
    }, function () {
        $('#StateWhite').attr("src", originalSrc);
        });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have two images load and position absolute them and just display none one on hover?

Comment: I have that on other parts of my website, and you're right it may be easier. Problems with my website and using absolute, the images aren't always placed where I want them to be, and that creates more problems later. I have had issues with layering images and getting the whole image to sit where I want it.

Comment: Some general tips: [1] use `$(this).attr` everywhere, instead of sometimes `$('#StateWhite').attr`, it will be more clear what your intentions are and is also easier to maintain. [2] add `if(originalSrc)` to the second function so it will not act unless `originalSrc` is set.